# Convert a date string into proper date stamp in MYSQL (I need the sql code, not php)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a huge spreadsheet with four date columns for the details of various orders that I'm importing from one system to another.

The dates currently look like this in the MYSQL database I created from the spreadsheet:

Sun Nov 27 17:02:40 PST 2011

Sat Nov 26 17:01:54 PST 2011

Mon Nov 28 18:06:29 PST 2011

and I want them to be simply a date stamp that I can query for running reports against in MYSQL.  I'm not using PHP right now and I want to be able to do this conversion in MySQL.  I've found similar threads, but nothing that was helpful for this particular approach.  Apologies if it's been addressed somewhere already.

Comment: What is the data type of the database column? Also, googling "mysql date functions" isn't that hard.

Comment: I did my GoogleFoo...but wasn't able to find how to do a match on this string (it's a string) and change it to datetime.

Comment: The column type is varchar.  Changing the columns to datetime erases the values....

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
select str_to_date('Sun Nov 27 17:02:40 PST 2011', '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s PST %y')
```

I don't think you can convert the timezone name properly though.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I knew I could look up the actual formatting bit, but wasn't familiar (or was able to find) how to knit it together into a select statement.

Comment: Not the answer after all as I have so many many many rows all with varying time stamps that I can't feed str_to_date the straight string.  I have to identify a pattern for MySQL to match instead and then based on that match, then format the date.

Comment: You learned the hard way that it's a very bad idea to store dates in a varchar column. You should migrate that to a real `date` column as soon as possible (you probably need a little program for that)

Comment: These were dates imported into SQL Server from a spreadsheet that came from some other source I have no control over.